# how to install a new module in metasploit?

Tags: ubuntu

I was just trying to install this module.
https://github.com/leonjza/metasploit-modules/tree/master/post/hardware/rftransceiver

When i try to install , creating the folder and copy the file in a new folder over the windows folder, show me the following error.

```
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/module_set.rb:191:in `add_module': undefined method `framework=' for #<Module:0x000055b8c8f9e3c8> (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/module_manager/loading.rb:73:in `on_module_load'
    from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/modules/loader/base.rb:183:in `load_module'
    from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/modules/loader/base.rb:238:in `block in load_modules'
    from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/modules/loader/directory.rb:50:in `block (2 levels) in each_module_reference_name'
    from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rex-core-0.1.12/lib/rex/file.rb:133:in `block in find'
    from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rex-core-0.1.12/lib/rex/file.rb:132:in `catch'
    from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rex-core-0.1.12/lib/rex/file.rb:132:in `find'
    from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/modules/loader/directory.rb:40:in `block in each_module_reference_name'
    from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/modules/loader/directory.rb:30:in `foreach'
    from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/modules/loader/directory.rb:30:in `each_module_reference_name'
    from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/modules/loader/base.rb:237:in `load_modules'
    from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/module_manager/loading.rb:119:in `block in load_modules'
    from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/module_manager/loading.rb:117:in `each'
    from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/module_manager/loading.rb:117:in `load_modules'
    from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/module_manager/module_paths.rb:41:in `block in add_module_path'
    from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/module_manager/module_paths.rb:40:in `each'
    from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/module_manager/module_paths.rb:40:in `add_module_path'
    from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/base/simple/framework/module_paths.rb:50:in `block in init_module_paths'
    from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/base/simple/framework/module_paths.rb:49:in `each'
    from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/base/simple/framework/module_paths.rb:49:in `init_module_paths'
    from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/ui/console/driver.rb:196:in `initialize'
    from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/metasploit/framework/command/console.rb:62:in `new'
    from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/metasploit/framework/command/console.rb:62:in `driver'
    from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/metasploit/framework/command/console.rb:48:in `start'
    from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/metasploit/framework/command/base.rb:82:in `start'
    from /usr/bin/msfconsole:48:in `<main>'
root@android-HP-ProBook-6550b:/usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/exploits/windows/download#
```

Comment: Question unclear. Follow this guide: https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/wiki/Loading-External-Modules

Comment: i tried that but my question is how to put it .i tried with linux and got the errors of my post. but now i was trying with windows to add new module i tried but metasploit never load the new module.

Comment: From the link I sent you: "Sadly, you're a little out of luck; the module load paths on Windows are a little more restrictive and don't allow for external modules. "

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this on windows. From the official documentation:

> "Sadly, you're a little out of luck; the module load paths on Windows
>   are a little more restrictive and don't allow for external modules. "

**Source:** https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/wiki/Loading-External-Modules

**SOLUTION:** Use Kali Linux. It will make your life easier.

Comment: kali linux is a pick in the ass. i really prefer ubuntu instead. make the life more easier. anyways i loaded the test module in windows and worked? why then?